# CSS transition-property auto height in augularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, less, pug

Following coding is to expand Div when mouse hover its space using CSS `transition`. The problem is height in that `transaction` can be defined specific **height**. Defining specific height can be workable for only desktop version but for mobile version, that's gonna be problem.

For desktop version, specific list in is three columns thus defining specific height is Ok. For mobile version, I merge these three column to be one column thus defining specific height is not ok.

```
div.mycolumn {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}

div.mycolumn:hover {
 max-height: 500px; <<<< WANT AUTO HEIGHT INSTEAD
 transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

My question it AngularJs can be get specific height of current Div and pass it into CSS, (i'm using LESS instead.)

```
div.mycolumn
    .container
        .row
            .col-xs-4.col-sm-12
                .row(data-ng-repeat="data in mydata1")
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-3
                        {{data.myname}}
            .col-xs-4.col-sm-12
                .row(data-ng-repeat="data in mydata2")
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-3
                        {{data.myname}}
            .col-xs-4.col-sm-12
                .row(data-ng-repeat="data in mydata3")
                    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-3
                        {{data.myname}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.category-box {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

//For Mobile
.category-box {
  &.show {
    max-height: 999px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  }
}

//For Desktop
@media screen and (min-width: 48em){
  .category-box {
    &.show {
      max-height: 500px;
      transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
    }
  }
}
```

Above codes are workable for my question.